# Toggle particular div on particular button click using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

> I'm used PHP and Jquery to toggle div on button click.
>   I want toggle div on specific button to specific div.
>   For Example : if I'm click on 3rd button than its toggle only 3rd div with its content.
>   ** Using Class not By Id because this div and button series is not fix.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hide-demo").click(function(){
    $(".hideDemo").toggle();
  });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 1</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
  <h1>Demo 1</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 2</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
  <h1>Demo 2</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 3</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
  <h1>Demo 3</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 4</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
  <h1>Demo 4</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 5</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
  <h1>Demo 5</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The current selector (`$(".hideDemo")`) is attaching `toggle()` to all the `div` with class `hideDemo`. You have to use `this` and `next()` to implement `toggle()` to the specific element you intend to.

Change

```
$(".hideDemo").toggle();
```

To

```
 $(this).next(".hideDemo").toggle();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hide-demo").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".hideDemo").toggle();
  });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 1</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
    <h1>Demo 1</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 2</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
    <h1>Demo 2</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 3</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
    <h1>Demo 3</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 4</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
    <h1>Demo 4</h1>
</div>

<button class="hide-demo">Hide / Show 5</button>
<div class="hideDemo">
    <h1>Demo 5</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this js code, I think it'll do what you want according to your html structure

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hide-demo").click(function(){
            $(this).next().toggle()
        });    
    });
```